# TraceListener call does not block, leads to crash when calling twice

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

My setup: simple implementation of `TraceListener` that is instantiated **once** and keeps **one** instance of a "MessageBox" implementation.
It's purpose is to listen for binding errors, as it is added to `PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners`

My test case opens a window that has exactly `two` binding errors, so what I expect is, the tracer kicks in and shows the "MessageBox" window via `ShowDialog()`. The user clicks ok, the window is **NOT** closed, but hidden and the second binding error should came up.
Instead I get a crash:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> > "ShowDialog" can only be called on hidden windows

Why the heck does this happen? Here is the exact implementation of the trace listener:

```
public class DummyListener : TraceListener
{
    private readonly MessageBoxView _window = new MessageBoxView();

    public DummyListener()
    {
        _window.HideOnClose = true;
        _window.DataContext = _window;
    }

    public override void Write( string message )
    {
    }

    public override void WriteLine( string message )
    {
        lock ( _window )
        {
            if ( _window.IsActive )
            {
                // !!! WHY IS THIS CODE EXECUTED
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
            _window.Message = message;
            _window.ShowDialog();

            throw new NotImplementedException("This line is never reached");
        }
    }

}
```

I've added a lock just for testing. The _window.ShowDialog is called twice, for each binding error and then crashes. The `NotImplementedException` is also a test, it never gets called. So first binding error calls _window.ShowDialog(), this seems to **block** but the trace listener source calls `WriteLine` a second time, on the **same** thread, it ignores the lock and enters my `Break()` call, if I continue, it calls `_window.ShowDialog()` before the first dialog got hidden.
If I replace `_window.ShowDialog` with a `MessageBox.Show`, it does really block.
Why does ShowDialog() behaves this way? It does block, as the NIE exception after it is not thrown but why does the `System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.TraceEvent` re-enter the **locked** section?

For clarification: I want to pool the window, I do not want to spawn multiple message box window but show them in order.
I've checked the threads, everything happens on the main thread, but nothing blocks the way I would expect.

Here is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (sorry it is quite verbose as I could not reduce it more):

It opens a window directly, it throws the above exception because of _window.ShowDialog();

App.xaml (remove the startup uri)

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplicationTracerIssue2.App"

             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             >
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplicationTracerIssue2
{
    public class DummyListener : TraceListener
    {
        private readonly MessageBoxView _window = new MessageBoxView();

        public DummyListener()
        {
            _window.HideOnClose = true;
            _window.DataContext = _window;
        }

        public override void Write( string message )
        {
        }

        public override void WriteLine( string message )
        {
            lock ( _window )
            {
                if ( _window.IsActive )
                {
                    // !!! WHY IS THIS CODE EXECUTED
                    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                }
                _window.Title = "Log entry occurred";
                _window.Message = message;
                _window.ShowDialog();

                throw new NotImplementedException("This line is never reached");
            }
        }

    }

    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private DummyListener dl = new DummyListener();

        protected override void OnStartup( StartupEventArgs e )
        {
            base.OnStartup( e );
            Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;

            PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add( dl );

            var d = new MainWindow();

            d.DataContext = d;
            MainWindow = d;
            d.Show(); 
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml (cs is default)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationTracerIssue2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding A}"></Label>
        <Label Content="{Binding B}"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Finally the dummy messagebox view:

MessageBoxView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationTracerIssue2.MessageBoxView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MessageBoxView" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Message}" ContentStringFormat="msg: {0}"></Label>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Ok</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MessageBoxView.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplicationTracerIssue2
{

    public partial class MessageBoxView : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Message", typeof ( string ), typeof ( MessageBoxView ), new PropertyMetadata( default( string ) ) );

        public string Message{ get { return ( string ) GetValue( MessageProperty ); } set { SetValue( MessageProperty, value ); }}


        public MessageBoxView(){InitializeComponent();}

        public bool HideOnClose { get; set; }


        private void ButtonBase_OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            if ( HideOnClose ){ Hide(); }
            else{ Close(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Evidently `_window.ShowDialog` uses your WPF application's message loop whereas `MessageBox.Show` uses its own, so new and pending Windows messages are dispatched while the former is displayed but not the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this doesn't appear to have anything to do with multithreading. It's really about re-entrancy in a *single* thread.

The issue is that the `ShowDialog()` method necessarily includes a message pump for the thread messages. The thread message queue is used by the listener framework to deliver events to the listener. So while you are displaying the window for the first message, that message pump in the `ShowDialog()` method goes ahead and delivers the second message, before the window for the first message has been dismissed.

One way to fix this would be to change the listener code so that it queued the messages itself, and displayed them on at a time. That might look something like this:

```
public class DummyListener : TraceListener
{
    private readonly MessageBoxView _window = new MessageBoxView();
    private readonly BlockingCollection<string> _messages = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    public DummyListener()
    {
        _window.HideOnClose = true;
        _window.DataContext = _window;

        PresentMessages();
    }

    private async void PresentMessages()
    {
        IEnumerator<string> enumerator = _messages.GetConsumingEnumerable().GetEnumerator();

        while (await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => enumerator.MoveNext(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning))
        {
            _window.Title = "Log entry occurred";
            _window.Message = enumerator.Current;
            _window.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        _messages.Add(message);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _messages.CompleteAdding();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

The above uses a `BlockingCollection<string>` to queue up each message as it comes in. Also, in the constructor it calls an `async` method that handles the actual presentation of the window.

That `PresentMessages()` method uses an asynchronous task to wait for a message to be available to present. When that task completes, the method is resumed in the original thread to present the window.

**NOTE:** for the above to work, you need to ensure that the listener class instance itself is created in the UI thread, so that the continuation in the `PresentMessages()` method is in fact executed in the UI thread too. To ensure that, I changed your `App` code so it looks like this instead:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private DummyListener dl;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;

        dl = new DummyListener();
        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add(dl);

        var d = new MainWindow();

        d.DataContext = d;
        MainWindow = d;
        d.Show();
    }
}
```

Also note that I use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` to create the task, rather than the more concise `Task.Run()`. This allows me to pass `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`, so that the `Task` class knows this operation could take a long time. That way it can avoid tying up a thread pool thread on a blocking operation that could potentially take a long time to complete.

An even better approach would be to implement an asynchronously-completing `MoveNext()` method (i.e. an asynchronous version of `IEnumerable<T>`). I leave that as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: I will elaborate this and mark it as an answer afterwards. But before: I must not set a limit onto the blocking collection, right? If the limit would be reached, it would block the caller in the Add, which would block the UI thread effectively blocking my notification window, am I correct?

Comment: Question: Why do I need to move the DummyListener ctor into OnStartup? I checked both versions and both versions call the ctor from the main thread, why does one of them fails?

Comment: @Samuel: yes, if you set a limit on the collection, adding will block. This is not necessarily awful, but it certainly can interfere with performance of any thread that could generate trace events and probably should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @Samuel: As for where to initialize, I didn't look very closely at the issue myself, but it's clear that when the initializer runs, it's either on the wrong thread or (more likely, since initializer should run in the same thread as constructor) the dispatcher isn't present yet and so the listener is initialized improperly. Putting in the constructor guarantees the right sequence of initialization to ensure everything works.